# Смена роутинга для компонентов

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

У меня есть три компонента:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Home extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>Home</h2>
            </div>
        );
    }

}

export default Home;

import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Task extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>Task</h2>
            </div>
        );
    }

}

export default Task;

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class User extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>User</h2>
               // <Link to='/task'>???</Link>                
            </div>
        );
    }

}

export default User;
```

И мой index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Route, BrowserRouter, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import Home from './components/Home';
import User from './components/User';

ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
            <Route path='/user' component={User} />
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>, 
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Есть два компонента, которые мапятся на два урла, как сделать так, чтобы третий компонент рендерился отдельно, при нажатии на что-нибудь(кнопка или ссылка), чтобы урл не менялся. То есть отрендерился другой компонент, а адрес остался тот же.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// ./src/Home
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Home extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>Home</h2>
            </div>
        );
    }

}

export default Home;

// ./src/Task
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Task extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>Task</h2>
            </div>
        );
    }

}

export default Task;

// ./src/User
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Task from "./Task"

class User extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        
        this.state = {
            showTask: false
        };
        
        this.toggleTaskShow = this.toggleTaskShow.bind(this);
    }
    
    toggleTaskShow() {
        this.setState({
            showTask: !this.state.showTask
        })
    }

    render() {
        const { showTask } = this.state;
        
        return (
            <div>
                {
                    showTask? (
                        <Task />
                    ) : (
                        <h2>User</h2>
                    )
                }
                <button onClick={this.toggleTaskShow}>Task</button>
            </div>
        )
    }

}

export default User;
```